# Python, tkinter: Can't save with Pickle

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pickle

I don't understand why my code won't save/load anything.

I want the user to be able to input one or several tasks in the GUI and then save them in order to be able to load them at a later point. I have done this successfully in another GUI before and just used the same approach for this, however it just won't work.
It doesn't load anything if I press load, and what goes on with the saving is a bit unclear to me.

If I run the program, add a task, save it, then delete it and press "*Load tasks*" it displays something like *<**main**.Task object at 0x0000018971142F10>* in the listbox:

[image: As displayed here]

If I create a task, save it, close the program and run it again and press "*Load tasks*" nothing happens.

Code:

```
import tkinter.messagebox
import pickle


task_list = []

class Task:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.name = n

def show_tasks():
    task = task_list[-1]

def open_add_task():
    taskwin = Toplevel(root)
    taskwin.focus_force()
    
    #name
    titlelabel = Label(taskwin, text='Title task concisely:', font=('Roboto',11,'bold')).grid(column=1, row=0)
    name_entry = Entry(taskwin, width=40, justify='center')
    name_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)
    

        
    def add_task():
        if name_entry.get() != '': 
                
            task_list.append(Task(name_entry.get()))
            show_tasks()
            listbox_tasks.insert(tkinter.END, name_entry.get())
            name_entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
            taskwin.destroy()
        else:
            tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title='Whoops', message='You must enter a task')

        
    Add_button = Button(taskwin, text='Add', font=('Roboto',10), command=add_task).grid(column=1, row=2)

    
def delete_task():
    try:
        task_index = listbox_tasks.curselection()[0]
        listbox_tasks.delete(task_index)
    except:
        tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title='Error', message='You must select a task to delete')

def save_tasks():
    tasks = listbox_tasks.get(0, listbox_tasks.size())
    pickle.dump(tasks, open('Todo.dat', 'wb'))


def load_tasks():
    try:
        tasks = pickle.load(open('Todo.dat', 'rb'))
        listbox_tasks.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        for task in task_list:
            listbox_tasks.insert(tkinter.END, task)
    except:
        tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title='Error', message='You have no tasks')
    

root = Tk()

task_frame = Frame()
# UI
your_tasks_label = Label(root, text='THESE ARE YOUR TASKS:', font=('Roboto',10, 'bold'), justify='center')
your_tasks_label.pack()

listbox_tasks = tkinter.Listbox(root, height=10, width=50, font=('Roboto',10), justify='center') 
listbox_tasks.pack()




#BUTTONS
New_Task_Button = Button(root, text='New Task', width=42, command=open_add_task)
New_Task_Button.pack()

button_delete_task = Button(root, text='Delete task', width=42, command=delete_task)
button_delete_task.pack()


button_save_tasks = Button(root, text='Save tasks', width=42, command=save_tasks)
button_save_tasks.pack()

button_load_tasks = Button(root, text='Load tasks', width=42, command=load_tasks)
button_load_tasks.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The problem is in this line `for task in task_list:` you are trying to read from saved list not from pickle file it should instead be `for task in tasks:`.

Comment: Can't you use `listbox_tasks.get(0, "end")` instead of `listbox_tasks.get(0, listbox_tasks.size())`? It is much easier to type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments that the problem was that you were trying to read from the list which contained objects of the `Task` class. To access the contents of the Task you have to use `object.name`.

Since you used the `tasks` variable to store the contents of the pickle file you need to use the same in the `for` loop.

I would also like to inform you that when you are loading from a pickle file, after closing the application, you are not inserting it into your `task_list`.

I would suggest you make a separate function just to insert tasks to ListBox and save it a list, and call the same when you are loading from the pickle file.

```py
...
def open_add_task():
    taskwin = Toplevel(root)
    taskwin.focus_force()
    
    #name
    titlelabel = Label(taskwin, text='Title task concisely:', font=('Roboto',11,'bold')).grid(column=1, row=0)
    name_entry = Entry(taskwin, width=40, justify='center')
    name_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)
    

        
    def add_task():
        if name_entry.get() != '': 
            insertToList(name_entry.get())
            taskwin.destroy()
        else:
            tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title='Whoops', message='You must enter a task')

        
    Add_button = Button(taskwin, text='Add', font=('Roboto',10), command=add_task).grid(column=1, row=2)


def insertToList(task):
    task_list.append(Task(task))
    show_tasks()
    listbox_tasks.insert(tkinter.END, task)

def load_tasks():
    global task_list
    try:
        with open('Todo.dat', 'rb') as f:
            tasks = pickle.load(f)
            
        listbox_tasks.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        task_list = []
        for task in tasks:
            insertToList(task)
        print(task_list, tasks)
    except:
        tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title='Error', message='You have no tasks')

...
```